# Run a python function every 15 minutes and save files in different names

Tags: python, selenium, schedule

I am trying to run a function where I am downloading a file from a website and saving it in a particular directory.
I want to automate this using python. However, I need the name of the file to be changed every time(preferably a suffix addition of _&time.)
Using the below code, how can I change the file name every time i download?
For downloading:

```
def job()
        driver.get("website")
        time.sleep(60)
        download=driver.find_element_by_xpath("path").click()
        time.sleep(10)
        return()
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job) 
while True:
      schedule.run_pending()
```

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/59891729/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59891729/edit).

Comment: @user2458552 one option is to find pdf url and then get file with request and save into .pdf with different name

Comment: you can download a file and check after download you can rename filename

Answer (score 0):

You can find the latest downloaded file and then rename it.
 You have to edit your script to :

```
import glob,os
def job()

        driver.get("website")
        time.sleep(60)
        download=driver.find_element_by_xpath("path").click()
        time.sleep(10)
        list_of_files=glob.glob(<path_to_download>/*)
        latest_file=max(list_of_files,key=os.path.getctime)
        os.rename(<path>/latest_file,<new_file_name>)
        return()
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job) 
while True:
      schedule.run_pending()
```